# Boost Python Tutorial Linker Errors

Tags: python, boost, boost-python

I would like to use the Boost.Python Framework.
At the Moment i am trying to get the Tutorial done. My Boost Version is 1.66.
I have Python 3.4 installed and my operating system is Windows 7.

What I have done so far:

1) Downloaded zip File for Windows: http://www.boost.org/users/download/

2) Unziped it in C:/boost => resulting directory is C:/boost/boost_1_66_0

3) Install Boost.Build (5.2.1 http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) with --prefix=C:\boost\boost_1_66_0\boost_build and the option --with-python

4) Added following user-config.jam File:

```
    using msvc : 10.0 ;

    using python 
        : 3.4                   # Version
        : C:\\Python34\\python.exe      # Python Path
        : C:\\Python34\\include         # include path
        : C:\\Python34\\libs            # lib path(s)
    ;
```

5) Changed the Jamfile in the Tutorial directory (C:\boost\boost_1_66_0\libs\python\example\tutorial) as follws:

```
    # Copyright Stefan Seefeld 2016.
    # Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0.
    # (See accompanying file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at
    # http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)

    import python ;

    project tutorial
      : requirements
         <include>../../../../
      <location>.
      ;

    python-extension hello_ext : hello.cpp ;

    run-test hello : hello_ext hello.py ;

    alias test : hello ;
    explicit test ;
```

6) Now in the folder are Jamefile, hello.cpp, hello.py.
7) Run in command prompt bjam toolset=msvc --verbose-test test

```
    C:\boost\boost_1_66_0\libs\python\example\tutorial>bjam toolset=msvc --verbose-test test
    ...patience...
    ...found 1029 targets...
    ...updating 4 targets...
    msvc.link.dll hello_ext.pyd
    Fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'boost_python.lib'
    call "C:\Users\YANNIC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_10.0_vcvarsall_x86.cm
    d" >nul
    link /NOLOGO /INCREMENTAL:NO /DLL /NOENTRY /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /MANIFEST/sub
    system:console /out:"hello_ext.pyd" /IMPLIB:"hello_ext.pdb" /LIBPATH:"C:\Python34\l
    ibs"     @"hello_ext.pyd.rsp"
       IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 EXIT %ERRORLEVEL%

    ...failed msvc.link.dll hello_ext.pyd hello_ext.pdb...
    ...skiped <p.>hello for lack of <p.>hello_ext.pyd...
    ...failed updating 2 targets...
    ...skipped 2 targets...
    ...updated 2 targets...
```

Where can i find this .lib file?

Comment: When i run in the command prompt where /R C:\boost\boost_1_66_0 boost_python.lib, i cant't find any matching file.

Comment: Do you really **have** to use bjam to build your projects? As in, is that what you would normally use? It's just that it's by no means a necessity to use boost.python, and this often tends to confuse people unnecessarily.

Comment: No i do not have to but i would like to use bjam. Thats my first bigger project with c++ so i do not have much expirience with cmake ore somthing simulare